# c++ read lines from csv and split elements by comma

Tags: c++, csv, fstream

Below is some sample lines of a csv file.I am only interested in the second, third and fourth columns. So I want to write a c++ program to extract these elements and push them to a struct I defined. Currently I know how to get the whole line, but don't know how to get a certain column.

How can I extract these columns?

```
1,4872,4873,0.19109237,f,
2,4874,4875,0.2774146,f,
3,4876,4877,0.1637944,f,
4,4878,4881,0.07772251,f,
5,4881,4879,0.1285009,f,
6,4880,4881,0.13613093,f,
```

My code to open the file and read lines:

```
void ReadGraph_FromTXT()
{
        ifstream graphData("new_network.csv");
        string line;
        while (getline(graphData, line)){
                cout << line << endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: You can get free code. but you'll have to show//put some efforts

Comment: Please search the internet or StackOverflow before posting.